# Taipy page control (button.)

Tags: taipy

Is there a way I can use the same button to connect and disconnect?

For this, I should be able to change button properties dynamically.

Connect -> Connected -> Disconnect.

these could be the state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partials to change the label of the button when it is pressed. The following code will display a button whose label will switch between "Connect" and "Disconnect" when pressed. Let me know if this fixes your issue.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui

connected = False


def button_press(state):
    if not state.connected:
        state.button_partial.update_content(
            state, "<|Disconnect|button|on_action=button_press|>"
        )
        state.connected = True
    else:
        state.button_partial.update_content(
            state, "<|Connect|button|on_action=button_press|>"
        )
        state.connected = False


page = """
<|part|partial={button_partial}|>
"""

gui = Gui(page)
button_partial = gui.add_partial("<|Connect|button|on_action=button_press|>")
gui.run()
```